# Insert Data from Dialog box into Firestore Database on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to use a dialog box to update the name field of the users collection in my firestore database. I tried the following code, it prints that its been added in the console, but when I check the database there's no update. What could be wrong?

//Dialog Class

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_name, null);
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    userId = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Edit Name")
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    DocumentReference userRef = fStore.collection("usersData").document(userId);
                    String newName = editTextName.getText().toString();

                   userRef.update("fullName", newName).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            Log.d("tag", "Name updated as "+newName+ " for " +userId);
                        }
                    });
                  }
            });

    editTextName = view.findViewById(R.id.name_edit);
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

[Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LWr5.png)
[FIREBASE CONSOLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBJUH.png)

Comment: In which place in the code do you have the line that "it prints that its been added in the console"?

Comment: @AlexMamo, the "Log.d..." part under the positive button on click listener

Comment: That doesn't mean that the operation succeeded. Have you tried to attach a complete listener to the update() operation? Is something printed out from there?

Comment: @AlexMamo, i did as you said (also edited it on the question above) it still doesn't update on the database, but prints on the console

Comment: Is the onComplete() even triggered?

Comment: yes it is @AlexMamo, as i can view the Log message inside the onComplete() in the console

Comment: So is this line `Log.d("tag", "Name updated as "+newName+ " for " +userId);` triggered?

Comment: yes the Log statement is triggered @AlexMamo

Comment: Then why do you say that nothing is updated? How do you check that?

Comment: @AlexMamo, what i mean is that even though the Log statement is triggered in the console, on my firestore DB there is no data updated...so i don't really know what the problem is

Comment: Please add a screenshot of it, so I can take a look.

Comment: @AlexMamo, I have edited the question and added the console image. The name doesn't change in the database even tho it shows in the console as updated and the new name

Comment: In the Firebase console, it gets updated?

Comment: No @AlexMamo, there is no update happening on Firestore

Comment: Show me also a print screen of your console.

Comment: @AlexMamo, I have updated the question with the image

Comment: That screenshot doesn't help. Please add a more detailed one, to see the entire document/collection.